# Including external scripting file from HTML is not working in Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

When i am calling scripts from online and writing in html itself. my code is working. like this 
This .HTML file is working in node.js.

**WORKING CODE:-------**

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Basic Chat</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <ul id="chat_head"></ul>
            <form action="">
                <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Enter</button>
            </form>
            <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
            <script>
                var socket = io();
                $('form').submit(function(){
                socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
                $('#m').val('');
                return false;
                });
                socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
                $('#chat_head').append($('<li>').text(msg));
                });
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

But when i am making everything local file everything is not working

**NOT WORKING:--------**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Basic Chat</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id="chat_head"></ul>
        <form action="">
            <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Enter</button>
        </form>
        <script src="script/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
        <script src="script/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
        <script src="script/srcpt.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**And i have added all scripting file to the `<head>` tag too and no use.** 
Help me out.

**NOTE:- I am running it in node.js server. Not locally like f:///. and while running html file directly from browser all scripts are working**

Comment: Look in the JS console. Are there any errors? Look in the Net tab of the developer tools. Is srcpt.js loading correctly with a 200 OK status and the expected content?

Comment: status is 404, all the js files are not getting included. i have explained it clearly

Comment: 404 is self explanatory. Either the URL is just wrong or you haven't configured Node to serve up the file for any URL.

Comment: @Quentin if so why it could able to read script when i am running this file locally? 404 is coming when i am running html from node server. And my actual question is this exactly, Why i am getting 404 when it is running from server while working file when i am running it from local.

Comment: Probably because **you haven't configured Node to serve up the file**

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="script/jquery-1.11.1"></script>
```

should be

```
<script src="script/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
```

perhaps

Comment: That was my typing mistake, and sorry for that. and its not working in all the cases

Comment: when running "locally", you mean `file:///` not a local http server, correct?